# Execute openrowset stored procedure, parameter use

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openrowset

Little bit of background information:

I have a stored procedure, lets call it SP1. SP1 calls another stored procedure: SP2. SP2 calls another stored procedure: SP3.

Now, the first stored procedure (SP1) returns a resultset. The resultset are parameters for SP2, this is done with a cursor.

Because of these nested inserts and executes, i have to use an openrowset dynamic SQL string to execute my stored procedures.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @P_Source               varchar(255)    = 'test'
DECLARE @P_Location             varchar(255)    = 'test'

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #tmp 

            SELECT * 
            FROM OPENROWSET (
            ''SQLOLEDB'',
            ''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'',
            ''set fmtonly off
            EXECUTE dbo.SP1      
                 @P_Source =    '''''+@P_Source+'''''''
                ,@P_Location =  '''''+@P_Location+'''''''
                 )'

exec(@sql)
```

(I have ofcourse created the table #tmp). I have more  parameters to be exact (12), all varchar, but I left them out to not make it messy.

I'm getting the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

am I using the openrowset command in the correct way with the corresponding procedure parameters?

Comment: why don't you use OUTPUT parameters instead?

Answer (score 0):

All those quotes get confusing.  By doing `select @sql` prior to the `exec` you can see what SQL Server is going to *try* and do.  Based on the query you've provided `@sql` currently contains:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp 

        SELECT * 
        FROM OPENROWSET (
        'SQLOLEDB',
        'Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',
        'set fmtonly off
        EXECUTE dbo.SP1      
             @P_Source =    ''test'''
            ,@P_Location =  ''test'''
             )
```

To help you build up to the final solution you could try having a dummy SP1 that takes two *numeric* parameters - that'll eliminate some quotes for you to worry about.  Once you have that working you can proceed to add string parameters until you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For sql linked server use OPENQUERY
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql
and sp_executesql

```
DECLARE @P_Source               varchar(255)    = 'test'
DECLARE @P_Location             varchar(255)    = 'test'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @Params NVARCHAR(500) = N'DECLARE @P_Source VARCHAR(255),@P_Location VARCHAR(255); ',
    @ParamsValue NVARCHAR(500) = N'SELECT @P_Source = '''''+@P_Source+''''', @P_Location = '''''+@P_Location+''''';'

SET @Query = N'set fmtonly off; EXECUTE dbo.SP1 @P_Source, @P_Location'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([Local],'' sys.sp_executesql ' + @Params + @ParamsValue + @Query +'''   )'  

INSERT INTO #Tmp
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: In his case [local] is not linked server, so at least he should create it first